# I cannot start Solution Explorer properly

Tags: c#, visual-studio

[image: My Solution Explorer]

[image: But I need to make like this]

As you can see above, I can't open the solution explorer like the 2nd picture. Can you show me how to open it like the 2nd picture?

When I create my project directly, the files do not come, so I have to choose from the folder myself. After selecting it does not work as I want

Comment: tag it with the correct tool

Comment: There's probably a button on the Solution Explorer toolbar to switch the view. You're probably in a folder view rather than a solution view. When I'm in folder view, that search box says "Search Solution Explorer - Folder View (Ctrl+;)", which is probably what that text of yours translates to.

Comment: Yes, I opened it as a folder view, I wonder how can I open it with a solution view?

Comment: Use the File menu to open a solution, i.e. an SLN file, and not a folder. Under the File - Open menu, I have a Project/Solution option (Ctrl+Shift+O0 and a Folder option (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+O). Use the former and not the latter. Once the solution is in your history, open it from there in future.

Comment: But when i opened as a SLN file there is no files inside the SLN file. https://imgur.com/a/cQikzec

Answer (score 2):

The images in the link you provided don't load properly.

Try clicking the Switch between solutions and available views button in Solution Explorer and selecting one of the project views below.

[image]

^ Double click the Solution item in the Folder view to switch to the Solution Explorer view.